# How to resize the window obtained from cv2.imshow()?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-manipulation

I started learning OpenCV today and I wrote a short code to upload (I don't know, if it's the right term) a random image:

[image]

It works fine, and I can open the image, but what I get is a big window and I can't see the full image unless I scroll it:

[image]

So, I'd like to know a way that I could see the whole image pretty and fine in a shorter window.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. The community asks you to not post images of code, but rather copy it as text to your actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resize the image keeping the aspect ratio same and display it.

```
#Display image
def display(img, frameName="OpenCV Image"):
    h, w = img.shape[0:2]
    neww = 800
    newh = int(neww*(h/w))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (neww, newh))
    cv2.imshow(frameName, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: From my point of view, this solution has the drawback (in general, maybe not in this specific case), that if showing the image is just for some visual inspection, and/but the image is actually further processed, you might lose "precision" or "information" if you shrink it just for the sole purpose of visualization. And, creating/passing a copy of the image will increase memory usage (again: might be a problem in general, not mandatory here).

Answer (score 17):

The actual "problem" comes from [`imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) itself, and is the following:

> If the window was not created before this function, it is assumed creating a window with [`cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ggabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3acf621ace7a54954cbac01df27e47228f).

Looking at the corresponding description at the [`WindowFlags`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3) documentation page, we get:

> the user cannot resize the window, the size is constrainted by the image displayed.

So, to work around this, you must set up the window manually using [`namedWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b), and then resize it accordingly using [`resizeWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga9e80e080f7ef33f897e415358aee7f7e).

Let's see this code snippet:

```py
import cv2

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')

# Window from plain imshow() command
cv2.imshow('Window from plain imshow()', image)

# Custom window
cv2.namedWindow('custom window', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.imshow('custom window', image)
cv2.resizeWindow('custom window', 200, 200)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

An exemplary output would look like this (original image size is `[400, 400]`):

[image: Output]

Using `cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO`, the image is always fitted to the window, and you can resize the window manually, if you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I [may arise from the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) that `cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` only works with the qt backend

Answer (score 2):

When `cv2.imshow()` creates a new window, it passes the flag `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`, preventing resize.

To **resize an already existent window**, you have to disable this flag:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cv2.imshow('image', np.ones((128, 128, 3)))
    cv2.setWindowProperty('image', 1, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.resizeWindow('image', 512, 512)
    cv2.waitKey()
    exit()
```

**Before**
[image]
**After**
[image]