# OpenCV Python Window scrollbar

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working with OPENCV to draw a ROI on an image:

```
    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread(input_img)

    # Select ROI
    fromCenter = False

    #Used to allow us to resize the windows.
    cv2.namedWindow('PDF Scanner', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    r = cv2.selectROI('PDF Scanner', im, fromCenter)

    #Old version. doesnt allow window resizing
    #r = cv2.selectROI(im, fromCenter)

    # Crop image. parameters are also the locations of the ROI
    imCrop = im[int(r[1]):int(r[1] + r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0] + r[2])]
```

The problem I have is that large images do not display very well (they either get squished, or they are too big to show on the screen). Is there anyway that I can get a scrollbar on the window through use of OPENCV or other GUIs such as tkinter?

Thanks

Comment: If showing your image in a downsized window, which fits your screen, is an option (i.e. no downsizing of your image itself!), please have a look at [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405999/11089932) from me.

Answer (score 1):

you already know about flags to `namedWindow` (WINDOW_NORMAL to make it resizable), so I assume that doesn't solve your problem to your satisfaction.

Get a build of OpenCV with fancy Qt-enhanced `imshow`, which implements panning and zooming. the Qt-enhanced variant of imshow has given me some trouble when I needed to react to mouse events, so that can affect selectROI. you'll have to try.